# How to add item per line in linux terminal bash `apt install` command?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, debian, apt

System is Debian 10 with xfce 4.
I usually use `\`  at the end of line when bash command has  multi parameters.Then I tried:

```
pc@server:~$     apt install -y ./code_1.54.1-1614898113_amd64.deb\  
    ./veracrypt-1.24-Update7-Debian-10-amd64.deb\  
    ./bcompare-4.3.7.25118_amd64.deb\  
    ./dbeaver-ce_21.1.0_amd64_a0667a.deb\  
    ./rstudio-1.4.1106-aqmd64.deb\
```

But I didn't get what I want. I know it's ok to use   seperate parameters,like:

```
pc@server:~$  apt install -y ./code_1.54.1-1614898113_amd64.deb ./veracrypt-1.24-Update7-Debian-10-amd64.deb ./bcompare-4.3.7.25118_amd64.deb ./dbeaver-ce_21.1.0_amd64_a0667a.deb ./rstudio-1.4.1106-aqmd64.deb
```

Is there any way to set parameters one per line when using bash `apt install` command?

Comment: Add a space in between the strings and the backslash  `./code_1.54.1-1614898113_amd64.deb \\`

Comment: @Jetchisel,then I can install multi packages in one intuitively clear command?

Comment: Try it and see, yes?

Comment: What you have should work, unless you are in fact using a backslash followed by a space followed by a newline.  The backslash must be the last character on the line. (You are escaping the newline.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell,typo mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, with 2 caveats. The backslash must immediately precede the `\n`, and you probably want to omit the backslash on the last line.  eg:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

for x; do echo arg: "$x"; done
$ ./a.sh foo\
>   bar\
>   baz\
> 
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
```

Note that by retaining the backslash on the last line in the above example, an additional (unescaped) newline is required to terminate the command.  Also note that the leading whitespace on subsequent lines is necessary, as the shell will literally ignore the escaped newline and merge the two arguments if there is no leading whitespace.  eg:

```
$ ./a.sh foo\
> bar \
> baz
arg: foobar
arg: baz
```

Comment: One further question,how to rewrite command with end of `\` when I use `sudo` to run?

Comment: @kittygirl ??  I don't understand the question.